Oracle ODBC connection using Python pyodbc module
I tried to connect to the Oracle database using Python and pyodbc. The installation of the ODBC driver was successful, but I am still encountering the following exception.
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM003', '[IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  126: The specified module could not be found. (Oracle in instantclient_23_5, C:\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-23.5.0.24.07\instantclient_23_5\SQORA32.dll). (160) (SQLDriverConnect)')
is it because of the ODBC installation issue, if yes how to un-install the driver as I was not able to find the driver in the system.

There is a buglet with this 23.5 version that is being patched. However, do you really need to use ODBC?  Oracle's python-oracledb driver has a lot more features - and doesn't necessarily need Instant Client.
